# How to convert dateTime format to display ie: 15 Nov 13:50

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want the output to be (dd MMM 24hr-time) ie: 15 Nov 13:50,
The code I currently have creates a date format of 15 Nov 1:50PM and I want the time at the end of it to be 24Hr, How can I do this?

current code:

```
CONVERT(varchar(6), sl.LogDate, 7) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, sl.LogDate), 100) AS LogDate,
```

output: 15 Nov 1:50PM

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: Refer This: 
  http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the usage of the `convert()` function

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below script - `CONVERT(.., .., 108)`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), sl.LogDate, 7) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CONVERT(TIME, sl.LogDate), 108) AS LOGDATE
```